# Error 404 when trying to access a Django app installed in a subdomain

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, subdomain, virtualenv

I just installed Django and create a project and an app following the basic tutorial part 1, I created a virtualenv since centOS default python version is 2.4.3, I also created a subdomain to work on this for the development phase. when I try to access like dev.domain.com/admin/ or dev.domain.com/ I get a 404 error, it's like django is not even there. When I run the server I get a normal response:

(python2.7env)-bash-3.2# python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
February 22, 2014 - 23:54:07
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'ct_project.settings'
Starting development server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Any ideas what I'm missing?

**EDIT:after starting the server correctly(with the right ip) I tried again and as a result I got the browser hanging. Then I went to tried an online port scanner and found out that the port 8000 is not responding, any ideas what I can try next?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by contacting the support service and asking them to open the port 8000 for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have you hosts entry on /etc/hosts like the following one

```
   127.0.0.1     dev.domain.org
```

By default Django start the dev web server on port 8000 and you browser is looking for the server on port 80 (default port for webservers) so you need to add the port at the end of the url

```
   http://dev.domain.com:8000.
```

if you want to start the server in default port 80 you need to specify it (migth need root or sudo):

```
    python manage.py runserver http://dev.domain.com:80
```

Comment: I think the subdomain is well configured since I put an index file at http://dev.domain.com and I can see it, is this assumption correct? then I tried http://dev.domain.com:8000  and it results in the browser hanging for ever.

When I tried this  python manage.py runserver http://dev.domain.com:80

I got

CommandError: "http://dev.domain.com:80" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: I tried again python manage.py runserver dev.domain.com:80 and I get Error: That port is already in use

Comment: Anyways I think it should work with dev.domain.com:8000  but it just hangs for ever, regardless of if the server is running or not

Comment: Does it shows something on the console? errors? you can always try using http://127.0.0.1:8000 to see if dev server is working.